# populate dependent select box through ajax call in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to poulate cities on behalf of selected state in select box. I am able to get the id of the selected state but unable to pass that state id to php function to get array of dependent cities. All this is in wordpress.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function ajaxSubmit(){

        var stateId = $(this).val();
        // alert("SID"+stateId);
        jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        action:'getDist',
        data: stateId,
        url: "<?php echo $adminUrl; ?>"
    });
}
    $('#billing_state').on("change", ajaxSubmit);
});
</script>
```

Above ismy ajax call and below is my php function to which i want to pass state id..

```
    <?php

        function getDist($id){
            global $wpdb;
            $dists  = $wpdb->get_results("select name from cities where state_id = ".$id);
            if($dists === FALSE):
                echo $wpdb->error;
            else:
            foreach($dists as $dist){
                echo"<option value=".$dist->name.">".$dist->name."</option>";
            }
            endif;
        }
        add_action('wp_ajax_getDist', 'getDist');
    ?>
```

after this i get nothing in cities select box..

Comment: Hmmm I think you code is too complex. First, why do you even use Ajax ? If all you want is to populate a second drop down list, you could just use a <form> with POST or GET and the php code would write whatever you want.   I would use Ajax if I needed the value returned by the ajax function call. Here, not only you don't specify an appropriate return type you could manipulate, you use the `echo` in a loop ; what's the format of the data returned by your echo ? Do you know json_encode ? Plus each time that loop is called you Ajax function is suppose to return...You are using the wrong approach

Comment: i do need to use Ajax cozz i want database to return table rows from city table according to the selected state in array format

Answer (score 0):

Not totally wrong approach...I was just missing the acction function in ajax..
here's update..

```
 $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
            url:"<?= admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>",
            data:({
                action:'get_city',
                state_id:stateID
            }),
            success:function(response){
                $("#billing_city").html(response);
            }
        });
```